# Show schematic diagram from file or APIs

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, render

In my c++ program(Qt environment), I have a quite simple data container with data like:

```
module A: 
  name=MA 
  port_input_1 
  port_input_2

module B: 
  name=MB 
  port_output_1 
  port_output_2

connection:
  MB.port_output_1 MA.port_input_1
  MB.port_output_2 MA.port_input_2
```

I would like to show the schematic of these data. Like a block with "MA" got two lines connecting to a block with "MB". But I don't want to develop from scratch, like zoom function. Drop connections.

SO I am think I can use some open source tool that I can call to the programme and send desctiption file according to that format so I can have the schematic directly. Or for the best, is there any library that I can use, give a description file and it just does the job for me

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.graphviz.org](http://www.graphviz.org).  It has a number of diagramming tools.  The **dot** program is used by doxygen to draw graphs.